# Neo4j Return all Nodes and Relationships where Sender sent more than 10 emails

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working with email data in neo4j.  I would like to find all relationships and nodes where the emails failed to be delivered and the recipient list was over 10 recipients.

Below returns just the Senders that sent these emails:

```
MATCH (a:Sender)-[:FAILED_TO]->(r:Recipient)
WITH a, count(r) AS failed_to_count
WHERE failed_to_count > 10
RETURN a
```

[image]

How can I modify this to get back the senders, relationship and recipients?

Like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to collect the "failed" paths for each sender, and return the path collections that have more than 10 items:

```
MATCH path = (a:Sender)-[:FAILED_TO]->(r:Recipient)
WITH a, COLLECT(path) AS paths
WHERE SIZE(paths) > 10
RETURN paths
```